# nginx error: (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, nginx

I am running Ubuntu Hardy 8.04 and nginx 0.7.65, and when I try starting my nginx server:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

I get the following error:

```
Starting nginx: [emerg]: bind() to IP failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

where "IP" is a placeholder for my IP address.  Does anybody know why that error might be happening?  This is running on EC2.

My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    keepalive_timeout  3;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types  text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml
    application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

and my /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com looks like:

```
server {

        listen   IP:80;
        server_name  example.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;

       }

server {

        listen   IP:443 default ssl;

        ssl         on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myssl.key;

        ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;

        server_name example.com;

        access_log /home/example/example.com/log/access.log;
        error_log /home/example/example.com/log/error.log;

        }
```

Answer (score 90):

> With Amazon EC2 and elastic IPs, the server doesn't actually know its IP as with most any other server.

So you need to tell your linux to allow processes to bind to the non-local address. Just add the following line into `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
# allow processes to bind to the non-local address
# (necessary for apache/nginx in Amazon EC2)
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

and then reload your sysctl.conf by:

`$ sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

which will be fine on reboots.

Comment: AWS services are opaque, and just slow down the whole dev process. Rackspace and Digital Ocean let you systems administer your own box when hosted by them without needing to rewrite a bunch of obscure config files.

Comment: Thanks @kirpit. The AWS server I administer has retained the same IP for 2 years, though I have always been told AWS servers are constantly changing IP. This is for a staging server so I can test 2 different versions of the live server, but I assume AWS don't cater for this kind of thing and expect you to spin up a whole new box.

Comment: I specifically had to do this on a new CentOS 7 VM at Rackspace.  I'm upgrading from CentOS 6 and checked that server to realize there are a ton of changes to this config file, so thanks for your answer as it helped me avoid other issues in my case as well!

Comment: Thank you very much, this also helped me in a PLESK-managed system where Plesk itself is delivered by an nginx!

Comment: For me this made my non-AWS nginx ingress unstable - requests started hang.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid hard-coding the IP address in the config, do this:

```
listen *:80;
listen [::]:80;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution for using Floating IP's on digital ocean with vestaCP, along with adding your Floating IP to the "NAT IP association" in the vestaCP control panel IP's tab, followed by changing the domains to use the floating IP in the Web tab.

Answer (score 6):

As kirpit mentioned above you'll want to allow linux processes to bind to a local IP address:

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf

# allow processes to bind to the non-local address
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1

sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then you want to add the **private ip address** that is associated with your elastic ip and add that to your sites config:

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

Reload nginx:

```
service nginx reload
```

All done!

Answer (score 1):

For people who might be dealing with this in the future, I just looked up my private IP in the AWS instance and bound to that.  I verified that nginx was able to listen publicly and perform my rewrite after that.  I could not do *:PORT as I had an internal server I was proxying to.

Answer (score 0):

There might be remaining process/program that's using/listening at port 80.

You can check that using netstat -lp. 
Kill that process and start nginx.

Comment: hmm unfortunately there's nothing listening to port 80.

Comment: Ah the problem was the IP I was using was the EC2 Elastic IP, not the private IP.  When I changed to the private IP, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

With Amazon EC2 and elastic IPs, the server doesn't actually know its IP as with most any other server. So in the apache virtual host files at least you put *:80 rather than your elastic ip :80

Then it works properly. So theoretically, doing *:80 for nginx should work the same but when you do you get [emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use). Haven't found a solution yet.
.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Network Manager, you have to wait to raise the network interface before starting the service:

systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service

Answer (score -1):

For Amazon EC2 and elastic IPs, `sysctl.conf` will not work as nginx still not listen on `eth0`.

So, you need to `listen *;`