# IP - Domain redirect using nginx + EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, nginx, amazon-ec2

I need to redirect users to my domain name if my IP is hit. 
I'm using an EC2 instance. I had to add this line to allow the instance to  bind public IP.

Following @kirpit's answer on [nginx error: (99: Cannot assign requested address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191509/nginx-error-99-cannot-assign-requested-address) i added this line in the file:  /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

and reloaded sysctl.conf

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Here's the nginx configuration I've tried so far:

```
server {
    listen 80;
}

server {
    listen MY_PUBLIC_IP:80;
    server_name MY_PUBLIC_IP default;
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://mydomain.in/$1 permanent;
}
```

If i replace MY_PUBLIC_IP with MY_PRIVATE_IP the redirect works but its a redirect loop. So i think somehow nginx isnt recognising my public IP.

How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_PUBLIC_IP;
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  $scheme://mydomain.in$request_uri permanent;
}
```

for some reason having the IP along with the port was causing the issue. The same when it was with private IP worked fine.

Anyways, working now :)