# 2 Node.js sites on NGINX on EC2 instance suddenly stopped working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm not a server expert so I apologise if this doesn't make much sense but I will explain as best I can.

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running Apache and Nginx, I have attached 2 elastic IP's to the server and mapped Apache to one and Nginx to the other. I have 2 Nginx node sites on there (express with Angular Universal), I'm using pm2 to manage the node apps as a reverse proxy.

The sites were up and working for about a month and have suddenly both disappeared.

- The Domain is pointing to correct IP.
- pm2 is running correctly.
- If I curl on the server localhost:4000 where the site is reverse proxied to I get the HTML for the homepage as expected.

I noticed an issue when I tested the Nginx config.

```
 nginx[26274]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address).
```

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141104/3604283

Which seemed to work, the Nginx test worked and the Nginx restart.
I then tried restarting pm2 again but still no site...

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Have you looked at the pm2 logs?

Comment: @PBurke No I hadn't, just seen an angular/node error in there, I will try and fix and post back if that solves it. Seems strange though if that is the issue because why would that stop my other sites on separate pm2 tasks from running?

Comment: @PBurke fixed the pm2log error. Sites will not load still, pretty sure this is related to ec2 and the IP/port that Nginx is mapped to

Comment: Solved with ip add

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an issue with the 2 elastic IP addresses, I did ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/20 dev eth0

but this doesn't persist between reboots, had to add that to a shell script and create root user cronjob on a restart to run it.